# How to stop a fixed gadget before the footer?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, footer, fixed

everyone! Searching the internet for solutions related to stick a widget in the sidebar I've found one that I liked. But, the only problem is that it doesn't "break" before the footer. I've already tried a lot of solutions, but without sucess until now. If someone can help me, I thank!

This is the original script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*<![CDATA[*/
// Sticky Plugin
// =============
// Author: Anthony Garand
// Improvements by German M. Bravo (Kronuz) and Ruud Kamphuis (ruudk)
// Created: 2/14/2011
// Date: 9/12/2011
// Website: http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky
// Description: Makes an element on the page stick on the screen as you scroll
// For Blogger by : http://www.makingdifferent.com

(function($) {
var defaults = {
topSpacing: 0,
bottomSpacing: 0,
className: 'is-sticky',
center: false
},
$window = $(window),
$document = $(document),
sticked = [],
windowHeight = $window.height(),
scroller = function() {
var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
documentHeight = $document.height(),
dwh = documentHeight - windowHeight,
extra = (scrollTop > dwh) ? dwh - scrollTop : 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++) {
var s = sticked[i],
elementTop = s.stickyWrapper.offset().top,
etse = elementTop - s.topSpacing - extra;
if (scrollTop <= etse) {
if (s.currentTop !== null) {
s.stickyElement.css('position', '').css('top', '').removeClass(s.className);
s.currentTop = null;
}
}
else {
var newTop = documentHeight - s.elementHeight - s.topSpacing - s.bottomSpacing - scrollTop - extra;
if (newTop < 0) {
newTop = newTop + s.topSpacing;
} else {
newTop = s.topSpacing;
}
if (s.currentTop != newTop) {
s.stickyElement.css('position', 'fixed').css('top', newTop).addClass(s.className);
s.currentTop = newTop;
}
}
}
},
resizer = function() {
windowHeight = $window.height();
};

// should be more efficient than using $window.scroll(scroller) and $window.resize(resizer):
if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('scroll', scroller, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizer, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
window.attachEvent('onscroll', scroller);
window.attachEvent('onresize', resizer);
}

$.fn.sticky = function(options) {
var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
return this.each(function() {
var stickyElement = $(this);
if (o.center)
var centerElement = "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;";

stickyId = stickyElement.attr('id');
stickyElement
.wrapAll('<div id="' + stickyId + 'StickyWrapper" style="' + centerElement + '"></div>')
.css('width', stickyElement.width());
var elementHeight = stickyElement.outerHeight(),
stickyWrapper = stickyElement.parent();
stickyWrapper
.css('width', stickyElement.outerWidth())
.css('height', elementHeight)
.css('clear', stickyElement.css('clear'));
sticked.push({
topSpacing: o.topSpacing,
bottomSpacing: o.bottomSpacing,
stickyElement: stickyElement,
currentTop: null,
stickyWrapper: stickyWrapper,
elementHeight: elementHeight,
className: o.className
});
});
};
})(jQuery);
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: How about some of that code indentation?